# How to (properly) reuse a SVG with linearGradient multiple times on a single page

Tags: css, svg, vector-graphics

I'm using the following SVG of a Google Play download button. There are 4 `<linearGradient>` inside `<defs>`.

`<linearGradient>` requires an ID for CSS to reference as a fill. I'd rather not use IDs since I'm going to have two of these icons on a single page, causing the page to have duplicate IDs. Any ideas of an alternative way to achieve this?

SVG Code:

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 135 40'>
            <path d='M130,40H5c-2.8,0-5-2.2-5-5V5c0-2.7,2.2-5,5-5h125c2.8,0,5,2.2,5,5v30C135,37.7,132.8,40,130,40z'/>
            <path className='st0' d='M130,0.8c2.3,0,4.2,1.9,4.2,4.2v30c0,2.3-1.9,4.2-4.2,4.2H5c-2.3,0-4.2-1.9-4.2-4.2V5c0-2.3,1.9-4.2,4.2-4.2 H130 M130,0H5C2.3,0,0,2.3,0,5v30c0,2.8,2.2,5,5,5h125c2.8,0,5-2.2,5-5V5C135,2.3,132.8,0,130,0L130,0z'/>
            <path className='st1' d='M47.4,10.2c0,0.8-0.2,1.5-0.7,2c-0.6,0.6-1.3,0.9-2.2,0.9c-0.9,0-1.6-0.3-2.2-0.9c-0.6-0.6-0.9-1.3-0.9-2.2 c0-0.9,0.3-1.6,0.9-2.2c0.6-0.6,1.3-0.9,2.2-0.9c0.4,0,0.8,0.1,1.2,0.3c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.4,0.9,0.7l-0.5,0.5 c-0.4-0.5-0.9-0.7-1.6-0.7c-0.6,0-1.2,0.2-1.6,0.7c-0.5,0.4-0.7,1-0.7,1.7s0.2,1.3,0.7,1.7c0.5,0.4,1,0.7,1.6,0.7 c0.7,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.7c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.5-1.2h-2.2V9.8h2.9C47.4,9.9,47.4,10.1,47.4,10.2z'/>
            <path className='st1' d='M52,7.7h-2.7v1.9h2.5v0.7h-2.5v1.9H52V13h-3.5V7H52V7.7z'/>
            <path className='st1' d='M55.3,13h-0.8V7.7h-1.7V7H57v0.7h-1.7V13z' />
            <path className='st1' d='M59.9,13V7h0.8v6H59.9z' />
            <path className='st1' d='M64.1,13h-0.8V7.7h-1.7V7h4.1v0.7h-1.7V13z' />
            <path className='st1' d='M73.6,12.2c-0.6,0.6-1.3,0.9-2.2,0.9c-0.9,0-1.6-0.3-2.2-0.9c-0.6-0.6-0.9-1.3-0.9-2.2s0.3-1.6,0.9-2.2 c0.6-0.6,1.3-0.9,2.2-0.9c0.9,0,1.6,0.3,2.2,0.9c0.6,0.6,0.9,1.3,0.9,2.2C74.5,10.9,74.2,11.6,73.6,12.2z M69.8,11.7 c0.4,0.4,1,0.7,1.6,0.7s1.2-0.2,1.6-0.7c0.4-0.4,0.7-1,0.7-1.7S73.5,8.7,73,8.3c-0.4-0.4-1-0.7-1.6-0.7s-1.2,0.2-1.6,0.7 c-0.4,0.4-0.7,1-0.7,1.7S69.3,11.3,69.8,11.7z'/>
            <path className='st1' d='M75.6,13V7h0.9l2.9,4.7h0l0-1.2V7h0.8v6h-0.8l-3.1-4.9h0l0,1.2V13H75.6z'/>
            <path className='st2' d='M68.1,21.8c-2.4,0-4.3,1.8-4.3,4.3c0,2.4,1.9,4.3,4.3,4.3c2.4,0,4.3-1.8,4.3-4.3 C72.4,23.5,70.5,21.8,68.1,21.8z M68.1,28.6c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.6c0-1.5,1.1-2.6,2.4-2.6c1.3,0,2.4,1,2.4,2.6 C70.5,27.5,69.4,28.6,68.1,28.6z M58.8,21.8c-2.4,0-4.3,1.8-4.3,4.3c0,2.4,1.9,4.3,4.3,4.3c2.4,0,4.3-1.8,4.3-4.3 C63.1,23.5,61.2,21.8,58.8,21.8z M58.8,28.6c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.6c0-1.5,1.1-2.6,2.4-2.6c1.3,0,2.4,1,2.4,2.6 C61.2,27.5,60.1,28.6,58.8,28.6z M47.7,23.1v1.8h4.3c-0.1,1-0.5,1.8-1,2.3c-0.6,0.6-1.6,1.3-3.3,1.3c-2.7,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8 s2.1-4.8,4.7-4.8c1.4,0,2.5,0.6,3.3,1.3l1.3-1.3c-1.1-1-2.5-1.8-4.5-1.8c-3.6,0-6.7,3-6.7,6.6c0,3.6,3.1,6.6,6.7,6.6 c2,0,3.4-0.6,4.6-1.9c1.2-1.2,1.6-2.9,1.6-4.2c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1H47.7z M93.1,24.5c-0.4-1-1.4-2.7-3.6-2.7c-2.2,0-4,1.7-4,4.3 c0,2.4,1.8,4.3,4.2,4.3c1.9,0,3.1-1.2,3.5-1.9l-1.4-1c-0.5,0.7-1.1,1.2-2.1,1.2c-1,0-1.6-0.4-2.1-1.3l5.7-2.4L93.1,24.5z M87.3,25.9c0-1.6,1.3-2.5,2.2-2.5c0.7,0,1.4,0.4,1.6,0.9L87.3,25.9z M82.6,30h1.9V17.5h-1.9V30z M79.6,22.7L79.6,22.7 c-0.5-0.5-1.3-1-2.3-1c-2.1,0-4.1,1.9-4.1,4.3c0,2.4,1.9,4.2,4.1,4.2c1,0,1.8-0.5,2.2-1h0.1v0.6c0,1.6-0.9,2.5-2.3,2.5 c-1.1,0-1.9-0.8-2.1-1.5l-1.6,0.7c0.5,1.1,1.7,2.5,3.8,2.5c2.2,0,4-1.3,4-4.4V22h-1.8V22.7z M77.4,28.6c-1.3,0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.6 c0-1.5,1.1-2.6,2.4-2.6c1.3,0,2.3,1.1,2.3,2.6C79.7,27.5,78.7,28.6,77.4,28.6z M101.8,17.5h-4.5V30h1.9v-4.7h2.6 c2.1,0,4.1-1.5,4.1-3.9S103.9,17.5,101.8,17.5z M101.9,23.5h-2.7v-4.3h2.7c1.4,0,2.2,1.2,2.2,2.1C104,22.4,103.2,23.5,101.9,23.5z M113.4,21.7c-1.4,0-2.8,0.6-3.3,1.9l1.7,0.7c0.4-0.7,1-0.9,1.7-0.9c1,0,1.9,0.6,2,1.6v0.1c-0.3-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.9-0.5 c-1.8,0-3.6,1-3.6,2.8c0,1.7,1.5,2.8,3.1,2.8c1.3,0,1.9-0.6,2.4-1.2h0.1v1h1.8v-4.8C117.2,23,115.5,21.7,113.4,21.7z M113.2,28.6 c-0.6,0-1.5-0.3-1.5-1.1c0-1,1.1-1.3,2-1.3c0.8,0,1.2,0.2,1.7,0.4C115.2,27.8,114.2,28.6,113.2,28.6z M123.7,22l-2.1,5.4h-0.1 l-2.2-5.4h-2l3.3,7.6l-1.9,4.2h1.9l5.1-11.8H123.7z M106.9,30h1.9V17.5h-1.9V30z'/>
            <path className='st3' d='M10.4,7.5C10.1,7.8,10,8.3,10,8.9v22.1c0,0.6,0.2,1.1,0.5,1.4l0.1,0.1l12.4-12.4V20v-0.1L10.4,7.5L10.4,7.5z' />
            <path className='st4' d='M27,24.3l-4.1-4.1V20v-0.1l4.1-4.1l0.1,0.1l4.9,2.8c1.4,0.8,1.4,2.1,0,2.9L27,24.3L27,24.3z' />
            <path className='st5' d='M27.1,24.2L22.9,20L10.4,32.5c0.5,0.5,1.2,0.5,2.1,0.1L27.1,24.2' />
            <path className='st6' d='M27.1,15.8L12.5,7.5c-0.9-0.5-1.6-0.4-2.1,0.1L22.9,20L27.1,15.8z' />
            <path className='st7' d='M27,24.1l-14.5,8.2c-0.8,0.5-1.5,0.4-2,0l0,0l-0.1,0.1l0,0l0.1,0.1l0,0c0.5,0.4,1.2,0.5,2,0L27,24.1L27,24.1 z' />
            <path className='st8' d='M10.4,32.3C10.1,32,10,31.5,10,30.9v0.1c0,0.6,0.2,1.1,0.5,1.4V32.3L10.4,32.3z' />
            <path className='st8' d='M32,21.3l-5,2.8l0.1,0.1l4.9-2.8c0.7-0.4,1-0.9,1-1.4l0,0C33,20.5,32.6,20.9,32,21.3z' />
            <path className='st9' d='M12.5,7.6L32,18.7c0.6,0.4,1,0.8,1,1.3l0,0c0-0.5-0.3-1-1-1.4L12.5,7.5C11.1,6.7,10,7.3,10,8.9v0.1 C10,7.5,11.1,6.8,12.5,7.6z' />
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id='SVGID_1_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='21.8'
                y1='33.29' x2='5.017' y2='16.508' gradientTransform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 42)'>
                    <stop offset='0' stopColor='#00a0ff' />
                    <stop offset='0.007' stopColor='#00a1ff' />
                    <stop offset='0.26' stopColor='#00beff' />
                    <stop offset='0.512' stopColor='#00d2ff' />
                    <stop offset='0.76' stopColor='#00dfff' />
                    <stop offset='1' stopColor='#00e3ff' />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient id='SVGID_2_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='33.834'
                y1='21.999' x2='9.637' y2='21.999' gradientTransform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 42)'>
                    <stop offset='0' stopColor='#ffe000' />
                    <stop offset='0.409' stopColor='#ffbd00' />
                    <stop offset='0.775' stopColor='orange' />
                    <stop offset='1' stopColor='#ff9c00' />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient id='SVGID_3_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='24.827'
                y1='19.704' x2='2.069' y2='-3.054' gradientTransform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 42)'>
                    <stop offset='0' stopColor='#ff3a44' />
                    <stop offset='1' stopColor='#c31162' />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient id='SVGID_4_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='7.297'
                y1='41.824' x2='17.46' y2='31.661' gradientTransform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 42)'>
                    <stop offset='0' stopColor='#32a071' />
                    <stop offset='0.069' stopColor='#2da771' />
                    <stop offset='0.476' stopColor='#15cf74' />
                    <stop offset='0.801' stopColor='#06e775' />
                    <stop offset='1' stopColor='#00f076' />
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

CSS:

```
.st0{
    fill:#A6A6A6;
}
.st1{
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    stroke: #FFFFFF;
    stroke-width: 0.2;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.st2{
    fill: #FFFFFF;
}
.st3{
    fill: url(#SVGID_1_);
}
.st4{
    fill: url(#SVGID_2_);
}
.st5{
    fill: url(#SVGID_3_);
}
.st6{
    fill: url(#SVGID_4_);
}
.st7{
    opacity: 0.2;
    enable-background: new;
}
.st8{
    opacity: 0.12; 
    enable-background: new;
}
.st9{
    opacity: 0.25;
    fill: #FFFFFF; 
    enable-background:new;
}
```

Comment: Are you going to embed these SVG documents in HTML?

Comment: It's a JSX file, but yeah, it'll ultimately just generate HTML.

Comment: Then duplicate IDs don't matter. Each SVG document is completely independent.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true for my case: In a React app, I have multiple SVG, having the same linearGradient background, and if I set a simple Id in the component, used in the fill attribute of a shape near, the gradient doesn't seem to be recognized, as the id is multiple times in the document. I have to repeat the gradient definition (which is the same...) in each SVG, and give it a unique (generated) Id, so that the fill attribute can find it... Isn't there a way to factorize a gradient definition so that I could use it multiple times??